# I cant pass client reference id with mode as subscription in Stripe checkout. Is there any way I can pass client reference id?

Tags: angular, typescript, stripe-payments

With mode as 'payment' , I can pass client reference id in stripe implementation. This is the code i have used
[image]

I have passed client reference id with mode as 'payment' and it worked in my angular project, but when i changed mode to 'subscription' the client reference id is not passing.

Answer (score 5):

I replicated the setup on my end and passed the `clientReferenceId` (see code below). I am seeing the `clientReferenceId` property on the `checkout.session.completed` event. Note, the prop is only available on the [Checkout Session object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-client_reference_id), so you will not see it on the PaymentIntent or any other objects.

On another note, client-only checkout is deprecated, I recommend following the [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) integration guide instead.

```js
await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    mode: 'subscription',
    lineItems: [
        {
            price: SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE,
            quantity: 1,
        },
    ],
    successUrl: `${baseUrl}/redirect`,
    cancelUrl: `${baseUrl}/`,
    clientReferenceId: 'testid',
})
```